# postgres on ubuntu wsl runs on ::1, not on localhost/127.0.0.1

Tags: python, postgresql

I'm running my application on ubuntu wsl(18.04) on windows. 
psql -h localhost -p 5432 -c "select 1" 
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
where as ,
 psql -h ::1 -p 5432 -c "select 1"

?column?

## ------

```
    1
```

(1 row)
I've listen_addresses = '*' in my postgresql.conf and pg_hba.conf has,

local   all             all                                     trust

# IPv4 local connections:

host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5

It was all working fine till i restarted my machine. :-(